# MIME- sending an email with an HTML file as an attachment?

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I am writing a script that creates multiple plotly interactive charts that are saved in HTML format. I want to write code that sends these HTML files out in an email as an attachment. I can't seem to find any documentation on this, only instructions on how to embed the HTML in an email which is not what I want. I just want to attach the file, just like I was attaching a JPG picture or PDF file.

Code I have so far, which just embeds the HTML:

```
import lxml.html
import smtplib
import sys
import os

page = 'report.html'

root = lxml.html.parse(page).getroot()
root.make_links_absolute()

content = lxml.html.tostring(root)

message = """From: <me@gmail.com>
To: <you@gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: %s

%s""" %(page, content)


s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail('me@gmail.com', ['you@gmail.com'], message)
s.quit()
```

Appreciate the help. I'd hopefully like to find a dynamic way to send files that are in multiple formats, so that I don't have to worry about different functions to send different types of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard documentation see third example with module `email`

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.examples.html#email-examples

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# And imghdr to find the types of our images
import imghdr

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Create the container email message.
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ', '.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'

# Open the files in binary mode.  Use imghdr to figure out the
# MIME subtype for each specific image.
for file in pngfiles:
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        img_data = fp.read()
    msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image',
                                 subtype=imghdr.what(None, img_data))

# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
with smtplib.SMTP('localhost') as s:
    s.send_message(msg)
```

---

**EDIT:** for other files you can get `maintype`, `subtype`

```
import mimetypes

filename = 'file.html'
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)

print(maintype, subtype)

# text html
```

Comment: this is for png files. How do I send an html file attachment? For example, if I have just one HTML file I want to send out, how would I do that? When I try the standard documentation you posted I get `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found`

Comment: see other examples in link - there is example with HTML+images as email content.

Comment: I don't want to embed html in my message.. I just want to send an HTML file- that's different

Comment: `HTML` is file like any image so difference will be `maintype='text', subtype='html'`

Comment: I added code which can recognize `maintype`, `subtype`

Comment: thanks for clarifying the types- didn't know that was the issue!

Comment: Sorry- how would I add html text to the body of message?